# How to use div class in dynamically jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I can animate div element in jquery. In my code is only on use to static. How to use dynamically.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html><head>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".chk1").click(function(){
            $("#box").animate({height:"100px"});
            $("#box1").animate({height:"50px"}); 
        });
        $(".chk2").click(function(){
            $("#box1").animate({height:"100px"});
            $("#box").animate({height:"50px"});  
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="box" class="chk1" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(152, 191, 33); height: 50px; width: 200px; margin: 6px;">
</div>
<div id="box1" class="chk2" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% red; height: 50px; width: 200px; margin: 6px;">
</div>
</body></html>
```

There are two div. If the first one clicked, that becomes bigger and the remaining one becomes smaller. The pattern followed for all the div. If i need to add one more div, at present i copy the jquery code. How can we add div dynamically. Can you Help?

thanks,
dinesh

Comment: You'll need to explain more: What exactly is dynamic? What do you want to happen? Please share more details/code.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by dynamic

Answer (score 0):

By giving both `div` elements a single class (`expander` in my example), you can make this more dynamic, and not have to repeat the same code twice:

```
$('.expander').click(function(){
   $('.expander').not(this).animate({height:"50px"});
    $(this).animate({height:"100px"})
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/RVCYz/

The same could also be achieved with `siblings()`:

```
$('.expander').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({height:"100px"})
       .siblings()
       .animate({height:"50px"});
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/RVCYz/2/

This will work perfectly fine no matter how many div's you add: http://jsfiddle.net/RVCYz/4/

Comment: Sorry to say these code is worked for jsfiddle. But doesn't work in my system. Can you please explain the code.

Comment: @dinesh - the code is *very* simple, and should be easy enough to understand - there's not much more I can add. Why dont you provide a small, self contained example of what your markup *really* looks like so I can provide you a working example.